# Microsoft Query in Excel - Casting types?

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, csv

I have an Excel workbook that has an external connection to a .csv file for a pivot table. One of the columns in the .csv - let's call it ID - has data such as '00000000000000101'. I have a simple `SELECT ID FROM DATA.csv` set up.

In Microsoft Access, while importing the table, I can classify that field to be text before running the query on it. However, in my current situation, Excel/Microsoft Query is taking it in as int. I looked up the CAST function, and proceeded to try

`SELECT CAST(ID AS TEXT)` and 
`SELECT CAST(ID AS CHAR(255))`

but both yielded me the error

> Incorrect column expression: 'CAST(ID AS xxx'.

Am I using the function incorrectly? How should I approach this?

If it is relevant, here is my connection string:

```
DBQ=C:\;Driver={Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)};DriverId=27;Extensions=txt,csv,tab,asc;FIL=text;MaxBufferSize=2048;MaxScanRows=25;PageTimeout=5;SafeTransactions=0;Threads=3;UID=admin;UserCommitSync=Yes;
```

Comment: I added the MS-Access tag to your question so it's looked at by the right people.  I forget if it's cast or convert in access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this by using a schema.ini file. This helps to specify how Excel/Microsoft Query should read the fields and it seems to work nicely. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: where is schema.ini file, can you please update @csg

Comment: Sorry, just saw this. Create a new schema.ini file at the same folder as the .csv file.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/schema-ini-file-text-file-driver?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

Try the CSTR() function, use `SELECT CSTR(ID)`
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/type-conversion-functions-HA001229018.aspx

Comment: That did not produce any errors - but unfortunately shows up in the same format (ie. 000000000101 -> 101). I guess Microsoft Query took it in as int before the SQL statement.

Comment: Just to get a better understanding, are you importing to an existing table via an INSERT or are you using the import wizard in Access?  If you are importing to an existing table, that table may already have it cast as integer.

Comment: I am not importing a table in Access - but rather doing an external connection via the Access text driver in Excel. I managed to fix it though! - by using a schema.ini file to specify how the .csv file should be interpreted. Thanks!